# How to draw an infinite long straight line on a specific angle bearing on google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to generate an infinitely long line on a some specific angle bearing, such as 30º or 45º starting from a particular latlng. How do I do that without knowing what latlng the line ends up? Is there any sample code I can follow?

[image]

PS
I want to draw the final result like this:
[image]

Comment: you mean you want it to loop around?

Comment: No need to loop around. Just point all the way pointing to the north or south pole. The line must always pointing to the same direction.

Comment: Or at least the line is long enough to reach the other side of the earth. I am not a mathematician. I simply don't know the formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the posistion of antipodes you can calculate this way :

```
newLat = yourLat*(-1)
if (yourLng < 0 ) {
    newLng = 180 - yourLng
} else  {
   newLng = (180 -yourLng)*(-1)
}
```